# Convert string containing decimal fractions to decimal

Tags: mysql

I have some string data in a MySQL, the schema is like this:

[image]

Can the data in the "apgarscore" column be directly converted to decimal in MySQL so that the results are as below?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible - MySQL doesn't have a fraction parser built-in, but you can implement one yourself using MySQL's set of string-processing functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html - I recommend using the `REGEX_*` family of functions as they're infintiely more flexible than ISO SQL's functions.

Comment: ok, thanks, I've found the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    apgarscore,

    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE( '/', apgarscore  ) <> 0 THEN

            CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX( apgarscore, '/' , 1 ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) 
            /
            CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX( apgarscore, '/', -1 ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) )

        ELSE
            CAST( apgarscore AS DECIMAL(10,2) )

    END AS converted

FROM
    tableName;
```

Comment: May I format your SQL for readability?

Comment: just go ahead, hope it can help others with the same case